# Why my Xeon E5-2640 v3 2.60GHz runs twice faster than my Xeon E5-4627 v3 2.6GHz

Tags: xeon-phi

I am struggling with the performance of the newly bought machine with the Xeon E5-4627 CPU. My experiment codes ran almost twice as slow on `Xeon E5-4627 v3` CPU than the same code ran on `Xeon E5-2640 v3` processor. 
I did some simple benchmark on these two machines. Here is the code

```
long N = 1 << 24;
double s = 0;
for (long i = 0; i < N; i++)
   s += std::cos(i % 360);
```

I compiled the code on the machine with E5-4627 as `g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -o test test.cpp` and ran the `same` binary execution file in these two machines.
The E5-4627 cost about `0.95s` while the E5-2640 cost about `0.36s`.

Both machines are with `Ubuntu 4.8.5` and the `g++-4.8` was used.

Comment: Run `perf stat test`, http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: it seems that the E5-4627 didn't run in its full power. The perf stats shows that its cycles speed is just 1.20GHz.